# How to Create TextEditing controllers dynamically and get each controler text by clicking on Submit button in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

**How can i add text editing controllers dynamically in flutter and get each of the controller text on submitting**

[Please find the below github sample project link i have created](https://github.com/Mallikarjun-0369/DynamicControllers)

Comment: you always create them dynamically: `TextEditingController ctrl = TextEditingController(...)` - there is no such thing like statically created `TextEditingController` - what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I want to create more textediting controllers by clicking on add more button and get each of the controller text.
**Please check out the image link here.**[Image link](https://imgur.com/a1rdubd)

Comment: create custom `StatefulWidget` then, which `State` class keeps `TextEditingController ` and builds `TextField` in its `build()` method

Comment: Could you share a, example code snippet to do like you said. or please look in to my github repository.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#step-2-subclass-statefulwidget